# Blazor WASM AzureB2C Login-callback 404

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, azure-ad-b2c

I have a .NET 6 Blazor WASM project. I am using MSAL to authenticate using AzureB2C. It's hosted in Azure Static Web Apps. The app has been live and working entirely as expected. I am now receiving a 404 error after a successful login redirecting to "authenticate/login-callback". This has never happened before. It's working from my local machine. I have looked through my commit history and I don't see anything that would affect it. I haven't made any configuration changes to AzureB2C since I got it working. I am just looking for any pointers on debugging it. When the redirect fails, it's just an Azure 404 page. No error messages. Nothing that might help. Any ideas on how to debug would be great.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with .Net 7 Blazor WASM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `staticwebapp.config.json` file in the client project's root folder solved it for me.

```
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html"
  }
}
```

As mentioned in this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-blazor